# After upgrade to magento2.4.2-p1, getting error "stat failed for static/frontend/_view/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico"

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.4.2, magento2.4.0

Upgraded to latest version of magento which is 2.4.2-p1.
Now static url's are coming like

> /static/frontend/_view/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico

and site is broken. I did not find any solution of why url's are being created **frontend/_view/en_US/Magento_Theme** instead of **frontend/package_name/theme_name/en_US/Magento_Theme**

Answer (score 0):

can you please try with below

```
sudo php bin/magento config:set web/unsecure/base_static_url http://127.0.0.1/m242/pub/static/
sudo php bin/magento config:set web/unsecure/base_media_url http://127.0.0.1/m242/pub/media/
```

and also check pub/static version sign is 1 or 0 using below command

```
sudo php bin/magento config:set dev/static/sign 1
```

Comment: already tried
actually, issue is tat it is making different path like _view/en_US/Magento_Theme. that's why it is not picking up the files

Comment: have you check with my updated answer ?

Comment: yes that thing also checked in my system
the dev/static/sign value will only add or remove versioning. but the path would always be _view/en_US, and that shouldn't be.

Comment: have you tried what compilation says ?

Comment: the compilation is working fine without any error. if you have an idea about using which file it adds the url for js and CSS. then it would be helpful for me. then I can debug...

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if your theme wasn't installed properly.

Does your theme show up if you go to Content -> Themes ?

If not, check the theme configuration and run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

It could also happen if you're running Hyva, and the page matches a fallback page, but no theme was configured. (Or again, if the configured theme wasn't installed properly.)